# После обновления phpmyadmin на ubuntu 18.04 появилась такое. Как исправить?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Deprecation Notice in ./../../php/Twig/Extension/CoreExtension.php#1608
array_key_exists(): Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated. Use isset() or property_exists() instead

Backtrace

./../../../../../../tmp/twig/98/98a2b70fd2fec6c94fb2de93d4387a38d42918bd2e7ae2dd74a0bf7d699029cc.php#181: twig_get_attribute(
,
,
,
string 'comment',
array,
string 'any',
boolean true,
boolean true,
boolean false,
integer 57,
)
Template.php#184: __TwigTemplate_56241df9bb9954dfa3c4d369ead822ae73f37182d48792d8630f7d47bc51f236->block_content(
array,
array,
)
./../../../../../../tmp/twig/14/140225b86f5189b2b9c1b26a37abf9bba65e1dcb9b20e027b9135eecad021a35.php#58: Twig\Template->displayBlock(
string 'content',
array,
array,
)
Template.php#395: __TwigTemplate_7badaaa2db5c1f30a793cfcb95b4b2c96f218ed51fe37316cd3613e8aa1e5f76->doDisplay(
array,
array,
)
Template.php#372: Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(
array,
array,
)
./../../../../../../tmp/twig/98/98a2b70fd2fec6c94fb2de93d4387a38d42918bd2e7ae2dd74a0bf7d699029cc.php#40: Twig\Template->display(
array,
array,
)
Template.php#395: __TwigTemplate_56241df9bb9954dfa3c4d369ead822ae73f37182d48792d8630f7d47bc51f236->doDisplay(
array,
array,
)
Template.php#372: Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(
array,
array,
)
Template.php#380: Twig\Template->display(array)
TemplateWrapper.php#45: Twig\Template->render(
array,
array,
)
Template.php#134: Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(array)
StructureController.php#1406: PhpMyAdmin\Template->render(
string 'table/structure/display_structure',
array,
)
StructureController.php#382: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\StructureController->displayStructure(
array,
array,
array,
,
array,
array,
)
tbl_structure.php#69: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\StructureController->indexAction()

Comment: Забыл написать. php 7.4

Comment: Версию какую утсановили? А вообще читайте информацию о версиях. https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads#support

Comment: Информация о версии: 5.0.4deb2~bpo10+1+bionic1
Версия PHP: 7.4.14

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена перезаписью файлов в папке /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ из скачанного архива с оф сайта